# ColorThief library is not producing same colors for a single image on different platforms

Tags: color-thief

ColorThief library is available for Javascript, Java, Android and iOS but it is not producing the same colors for a single image on all 4 platforms.Has anybody faced the same issue with this library?How can we make changes to produce same colors on all platforms.